# Getting the filename of where a function was called from

Tags: php, filepath

Is it possible (in an efficient manor) to retrieve the filename (and line if possible) of the previous command that called a function in another (included) file?

For example:

Foo.php

```
function foo() {
    bar();
}
```

Bar.php

```
function bar() {
    // some stuff that will show when the above is executed:
    // Foo.php, line 2 (last bit if possible)
}
```

Comment: I knew `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` only  :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats a job for [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php):

```
function test($param)
{
    echo "$param";
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
}
```

Comment: ah, perfect, was unaware of this AWESOME function!! what is the performance like?

Comment: @cgoddard Yep it is nice :) Never thought about the performance as I use it for debugging only. What if you profile it using xdebug? Would like to know your results..

Comment: @hek2mgl shouldn't imagine it would be too large if the limit is set to 1, but I shall let you know shortly

Comment: @Akam PHP is *deep*.. Even after years of development you'll find new functions you never imagined of. :) I like this..

Comment: yes, but I never needed this function, however, I will work on it from now to practice it

Comment: @hek2mgl righto, after a VERY preliminary test, calling `debug_backtrace` 1,000,000 times, when the limit is set to `1` it takes just over 2 seconds, but when it is set to `0` (the default), it takes about 8 seconds. But as I need it to check the last function, having it at 1 (and called once) takes 30us... I think its worth it

Comment: @Akam I completely agree with you, and I am very glad that you have found this as useful as I have. If you are interested, I am using it as part of an SPL autoload function that will load what is being requested, ordered by precedence of the callers "package" to improve performance. Already getting about a 30ms of 120ms (original performance time) boost :D

Comment: @cgoddard Thanks for your results :) what was the nesting level where you've executed `debug_backtrace()`, meaning how much elements where returned if you set limit to `0`?

Comment: @hek2mgl It was on a wordpress project I had worked on in the past, on the footer.php file, it was only 7 items deep though, but the performance slowed considerably, but that could be down to an increased amount of memory being allotted

Comment: @cgoddard Like that *performance hack*, without having seen it yet. is it open source?

Comment: @hek2mgl nah, tis a framework I built myself. I have been working on hiking the performance for a while. Having that doing the ordering by what was calling it was preventing it from scanning all the directories of the packages before it (which were superfluous), and saved it. There was a caching method in place to only do it once, but it was a very large directory with 216 files. All used for different aspects of the app in question